# Why does System Preferences > Display > Arrangement show two displays?

Tags: display, mac-mini

I'm using a Mac computer for the first time. It is a Mac Mini 2012 with macOS 10.13 installed. I hooked up **one** monitor to the Mac Mini.  Why does System Preferences > Display > Arrangement show two displays?

[image]

How do I get my Mac Mini to recognize that there is only ONE monitor display connected to it?

Comment: What model of Mac Mini and is [this](https://www.newegg.com/samsung-s24d360hl-23-6/p/N82E16824001912) the monitor you've connected? How are you connecting it -- HDMI, Mini Displayport?

Comment: @IconDaemon that is the correct samsung monitor you listed and I am using HDMI connection!

Comment: Does the Samsung monitor have a picture-in-picture setting?